# Rust Cursive EditView setText function

Tags: rust, cursive

My EditView is:

```
//.addChild( 
EditView::new().fixed_width(30).with_name("customer_names") 
//)
```

Now when try set content:

```
siv.call_on_name("customer_names", |view: &mut EditView| {
    view.set_content("helloooo");
});
```

Does nothing. :<

However, the textviews work well!

```
let view = siv.find_name::<TextView>("customer_id").unwrap();
view.set_content("this is ok helloo!!");
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
It didn't work because of the order of calling the functions. This is the creation of the editview:

```
EditView::new().fixed_width(30).with_name("customer_names") //no work
```

The search by name function was not finding the view. If I do so, if it finds the view:

```
EditView::new().with_name("customer_names").fixed_width(30) //this work ok!!
```

I have to put the **with_name()** first before other properties, otherwise it puts a wrapper on it and the editview doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In my case cursive did not find the TextView because it was a child of another NamedView. So I first needed to find the parent view and then the child view inside of it:

```rust
parent_view.call_on_name("child_view", |text: &mut cursive::views::TextView| {
    text.set_content(new_content);
});
```

This requires

```rust
use cursive::traits::Finder;
```

see also https://docs.rs/cursive/latest/cursive/traits/trait.Finder.html